# What is the purpose of maxNumberOfServerInstances in the NamedPipeServerStream class?

Tags: .net, windows-services, named-pipes

Currently writing a Windows service in .NET and I'm using named pipes to have other processes communicate with my service. In the more complicated constructors of NamedPipeServerStream, there's a parameter with a descriptive name of maxNumberOfServerInstances. Awesome. But what does that mean?

MSDN's documentation is also helpful at explaining:

> The maximum number of server instances that share the same name.

Okay. That still doesn't really tell me what this does for me, or how I utilize it. It would make sense to be if NamedPipeServerStream also accepted some delegate for "run this code when I receive a connection", so then each "Server instance" would then run that code. But that's not the case.

Comment: So, 9 years later and this question is still unanswered.  I think adding a comment to it might sort of bump it, in a way. Maybe. Kind of.

Comment: @RandomEngy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70475209/1768303) is the correct one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In practice it limits the number of `NamedPipeServerStream` instances you can create for the same pipe name. This will throw `System.IO.IOException: All pipe instances are busy.`:

```
var pipeStreamA = new NamedPipeServerStream("mypipe1", PipeDirection.InOut, 1);
var pipeStreamB = new NamedPipeServerStream("mypipe1", PipeDirection.InOut, 1);
```

If you change to -1 or 2, then it won't throw an exception. Also, it only respects the value on the first instance you create. If you specify 1 on the first call and 2 on the second, it will still throw an exception.

It's probably a good idea to set this to the maximum number of simultaneous servers that you expect to try to run, because as Hans mentioned, it may be using the number as a hint for the amount of resources to allocate.

Comment: This is the correct answer. A few more details in my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820831/what-is-the-purpose-of-maxnumberofserverinstances-in-the-namedpipeserverstream-c#comment124992266_8823964).

Comment: Does this mean that once `NamedPipeServerStream` is set, it cannot be changed to allow more instances until... all pipes instances with the same name get destroyed?

Comment: @MikeKeskinov Yes.

Answer (score 3):

It is an odd argument, you'll find a bit more info about it in the documentation for the underlying [Windows API function (CreateNamedPipe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Pipes use a very precious resource for the pipe buffers, they are allocated from the non-paged kernel memory pool.  I *think* this argument helps Windows optimize the usage of the pool.  Exactly how that's done is hopelessly undocumented.

The perfect number for a single service that accepts multiple client connections is 1.  You'd only increase it if you want to run multiple services that all do the same job.  That's pretty rare.

Comment: I don't think that's quite right. Each concurrent client connection exclusively uses one pipe instance: you can't have multiple clients connected to the same pipe instance (and likewise a .NET NamedPipeServerStream instance only connects to one client at a time). So a service which used 1 for this argument would serialize all its client requests. Rather, think of this as akin to the size of a connection pool - the service will want to set it to the number of truly concurrent client requests it is able to handle.

Comment: Stumbled upon this while dealing with multi-client named pipe server and I agree with @ChrisDickson. With sockets, `AcceptTcpClientAsync` gives us a new `TcpClient` instance for each client. With pipes, if we want multiple concurrent clients, have to maintain a pool of `NamedPipeServerStream` instances and proactively call `WaitForConnectionAsync` on each one. Naturally, each connection is still a one-to-one pipe, i.e., we can't have multiple client writing to the same remote end of the server pipe.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this problem with my VB code, and I set the number to 2.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim pipeserver As NamedPipeServerStream =
        New NamedPipeServerStream("myPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 2,
                                  transmissionMode:=PipeTransmissionMode.Message)

    pipeserver.WaitForConnection()
    'some process
    Console.ReadLine()  'do not exit until any key pressed
End Sub
```

With this program, "all pipe instances are busy" Exception happens if I try to start the third instance(EXE).

I have to close one instance so that I can start another one if the number of instances reached 2.

So I think this number is not related to clients, it just controls how many pipe servers can use this named pipe.